# Field Line Diagram for Small Bar Magnet in a Magnetic Field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I understand the resultant magnetic field diagram produced when a current carrying wire is placed in a magnetic field as shown in the diagram below.

[image]

However, what would this field diagram look life if, instead of a wire, a small bar magnet were placed in the field, either opposing or in the direction of the field?

Comment: Think about the superposition of fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The geometry of the lines depends on the magnitude of the external field. In fig. shows the case of a relatively weak external field.
[image: fig1]